# How to design in 10 inch tablet only in portrait mode in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml

[image]I have to design an application for 10 inch tab in Android.But when i run the application the design is in blur or not clear .I don't know why. I have also declare the `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in manifest .How to design properly and where I'm doing wrong in `xml file`.Thanks in advance.

Here is my xml file code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageLogoBBT"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/banya_tree_logo" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonBack"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/back_img" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relImagLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageLogoBBT"
            android:background="@drawable/inner_back"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#E6E9E9" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/APPLICATION_FOR_FUND_TRANSFER"
                    android:textColor="#32241F"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/APPLICANTS_INFORMATION_Detail"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTitle"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/APPLICANTS_INFORMATION"
                    android:textColor="#32241F"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearScroll"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/lastrowLayout"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/APPLICANTS_INFORMATION_Detail"
                    android:baselineAligned="false"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ScrollView
                        android:id="@+id/scrollFormOne"
                        android:layout_width="400dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.25"
                        android:baselineAligned="false"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="2dp" >

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/linearlayout_One"
                           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:baselineAligned="false"
                            android:orientation="vertical" >

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/linearlayout_textView"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:baselineAligned="false"
                                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                    android:layout_weight="0.10"
                                    android:gravity="left"
                                    android:text="@string/title"
                                    android:textColor="#241444"
                                    android:textSize="19sp"
                                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                                    android:gravity="left"
                                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                                    android:text="@string/last_name"
                                    android:textColor="#241444"
                                    android:textSize="19sp"
                                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                                    android:gravity="left"
                                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                                    android:text="@string/first_name"
                                    android:textColor="#241444"
                                    android:textSize="19sp"
                                    android:textStyle="normal" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/linearlayout_EditText"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                                android:baselineAligned="false"
                                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                                <Spinner
                                    android:id="@+id/gps_spinnertitleName"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                    android:layout_weight="0.10"
                                    android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:inputType="text"
                                    android:textColor="#241444"
                                    android:textSize="19sp"
                                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                                <EditText
                                    android:id="@+id/gps_edittextLastName"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                                    android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
                                    android:gravity="left"
                                    android:inputType="text"
                                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                    android:textColor="#241444"
                                    android:textSize="19sp"
                                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                                <EditText
                                    android:id="@+id/gps_editTextFirst"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                                    android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
                                    android:gravity="left"
                                    android:inputType="text"
                                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                    android:textColor="#241444"
                                    android:textSize="19sp"
                                    android:textStyle="normal" />
                            </LinearLayout>


                        </LinearLayout>
                    </ScrollView>

                    <ScrollView
                        android:id="@+id/scrollFrorm_Two"
                         android:layout_width="400dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.25"
                        android:baselineAligned="false"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="2dp" >

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:baselineAligned="false"
                            android:orientation="vertical" >

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:text="@string/Beneficiary_Address"
                                android:textColor="#241444"
                                android:textSize="19sp"
                                android:textStyle="normal" />

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/gspET_Beneficiary_Address"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="80dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
                                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                android:textColor="#241444"
                                android:textSize="19sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                                android:text="@string/Beneficiary_Account_No"
                                android:textColor="#241444"
                                android:textSize="19sp"
                                android:textStyle="normal" />

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/gspET_Beneficiary_Account_No"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="40dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
                                android:inputType="number"
                                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                android:textColor="#241444"
                                android:textSize="19sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                                android:text="@string/Beneficiary_Bank_Name"
                                android:textColor="#241444"
                                android:textSize="19sp"
                                android:textStyle="normal" />

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/gspET_Beneficiary_Bank_Name"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="40dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
                                android:inputType="text"
                                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                android:textColor="#241444"
                                android:textSize="19sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                                android:text="@string/Beneficiary_Bank_Address"
                                android:textColor="#241444"
                                android:textSize="19sp"
                                android:textStyle="normal" />

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/gspET_Beneficiary_Bank_Address"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="80dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
                                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                android:textColor="#241444"
                                android:textSize="19sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                                android:text="@string/BIC_Chips_ID_BSB_Code_Fed_Wire_ABA_Sort_Code"
                                android:textColor="#241444"
                                android:textSize="19sp"
                                android:textStyle="normal" />

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/gspET_BIC_Chips_ID_BSB"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="40dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
                                android:inputType="text"
                                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                android:textColor="#241444"
                                android:textSize="19sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                                android:text="@string/Intermediary_Bank_Name"
                                android:textColor="#241444"
                                android:textSize="19sp"
                                android:textStyle="normal" />

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/gspET_Intermediary_Bank_Name"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="40dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
                                android:inputType="text"
                                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                android:textColor="#241444"
                                android:textSize="19sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                                android:text="@string/Intermediary_Bank_Address"
                                android:textColor="#241444"
                                android:textSize="19sp"
                                android:textStyle="normal" />

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/gspET_Intermediary_Bank_Address"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="80dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
                                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                android:textColor="#241444"
                                android:textSize="19sp" />


                        </LinearLayout>
                    </ScrollView>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lastrowLayout"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                    android:baselineAligned="false"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="10dp" >

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/android"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.50"
                        android:text="@string/I_Accept_Terms_Conditions"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/buttonSubmit_Next"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="70dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.40"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
                        android:src="@drawable/next_btton" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Screen Shot 2014-06-24 at 4.05.30 PM

Comment: put the screen shot of tablet so i can find where is the problem

Comment: @Mahesh , Above i have post screen shot.

Comment: @Robotics : u r testing in emulator test in a real device

Comment: @Kaushik: No testing in only Emulator.

Comment: @Robotics : u don't get me i told u not to test in emulator.Test in a real `10-inch tablet` if u have one and follow the design pattern Vinakay show you.

Comment: create folder in res layout-sw720dp and put xml in this xml is or 10inch tablet

Comment: if you want to set form in two part then you can use weight use linear layout for weight

Comment: @Mahesh: I Use folder name layout-xlarge-port

Comment: use largesize image for 10 inch tablet and test in real device

Comment: @Mahesh:I'm using text box, edit text not images .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >

            // your left side part

        </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
            // your right side part

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

and also use different images for 10 inch tablets

Answer (score 2):

- Do not scale the images using `layout_width` or `layout_height` by your self. I can see in the `ImageView` you have specified `dp` values, this will make system to scale your image which may cause blur. Instead use size and density-specific resources inside drawable folders like

> ```
> res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png   //for medium-density screens
> res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png   //for high-density screens
> ```

- You can create specific layout suitable to the screen size and palce it in `res\layout-xxx` folders
- Wherever possible use [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) images
- If you have only one image and have to be scaled for different screen then use highest resolution image and keep it in drawable-nodpi folder and specify either height or width and lets system decide other so that image get scaled properly.

Read : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#screen-independence

Image scaling: http://argillander.wordpress.com/2011/11/24/scale-image-into-imageview-then-resize-imageview-to-match-the-image/

Comment: yes also vinayak is right you must not scale images using dp